# Suppose $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $ is convergent. Prove that if $c\in\mathbb{R} $, then $\left\{ cx_{n}\right\} $ also converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good morning! I wrote a proof of the following exercise but I don't know if it is fine:

Suppose $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $ is convergent. Prove that if $c\in\mathbb{R} $, then $\left\{ cx_{n}\right\} $ also converges.

Proof:

If $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $ converges, then by definition

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x.$$

For $\frac{\epsilon}{\mid c\mid}>0$, let $N\in\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$ be such that if $n>N$, then $\mid x_{n}-x\mid<\frac{\epsilon}{\mid c\mid} $.

Now, we have this:

$$|cx_{n}-cx|=|c(x_{n}-x)|=|c|| x_{n}-x|=|c||x_{n}-x|<|c|\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}=\epsilon\Rightarrow c\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=cx$$ and $\left\{ cx_{n}\right\} $ converges.

Please review this...

Comment: $c \in \mathbb R$ is usually written like this *c \in \mathbb R*

Comment: Thanks man, sorry but i don't know how write "∈" in LyX THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the meat of the problem, so I have a few smaller details to point out.

> $(1)$ Make a special case for $c = 0$. The quantity $\frac{\varepsilon}{\left| c\right|}$ only exists for nonzero values of $c$.
>
> $(2)$ When you say "If $\left\{ x_{n}\right\}$ converges then by definition
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x$", I think that is something that could be moved into the problem statement instead of needing to be stated during the proof. For example "Suppose $x_n \to x \ldots$" is a concise way to state that. By no means a big deal, but taking it out of the proof portion will shorten the proof, which is usually ideal.
>
> $(3)$ From here you have to manipulate your inequality to the point that it says $$\left|cx_n -cx \right|< \varepsilon$$ At this point exactly is when you have proven the claim. I do not see that concisely stated in your work; there is a lot of unnecessary inequality manipulation.
>
> $(4)$ Great contribution to MSE! Always glad to see when someone clearly shows their work.

Answer (score 2):

That looks fine.  You may want to comment that this only works for $c\neq0$ (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Of course, note that the proof for $c=0$ is completely trivial.